# SQL Server: how to avoid negative values in hour for Datediff in this format- Days:HH

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need result in Days:HH format and positive values in Hr.

As I am getting result in negative values as 0Day: -11Hr from this below query.
Here - `ad.notification_date` is the start date and `ad.decision_letter` is the end date, and `Admit_codes` ad is table name.

```
convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, ad.notification_date,ad.decision_letter)/86400)+' Day: ' 
+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s,ad.notification_date,ad.decision_letter)%86400/3600)+' Hr'as DAYs_Open from Admit_codes ad
```

And I have tried another two queries as below.

```
select
    DateDiff(dd, ad.notification_date, ad.decision_letter) As days,  
    + DateDiff(hh, ad.notification_date, ad.decision_letter) % 24 As hours
from 
    #AG_ADMIT_CODES ad

select 
    datepart(day, ad.decision_letter - ad.notification_date) - 1 as days,
    datepart(hour, ad.decision_letter - ad.notification_date) as hours
from 
    #AG_ADMIT_CODES ad 
where 
    'Days' is not null
    and 'hours' is not null
```

Please let me know how could I get positive result in Days:Hr format?

Comment: Can you post the DDL of `#AG_ADMIT_CODES`. I'm betting you aren't storing your dates as dates. To confirm this, sample data and expected output would be greatly beneficial. I understand you are new to StackOverflow, so reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with emphasis on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help you later on.

Comment: You are getting negative values because the two dates are in the wrong order.  Sample data and desired results would really help explain your actual intent.

Comment: Why don't you use `FORMAT` or `CONVERT` with a format specifier? What values are you trying to convert?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding this correctly, but use `ABS`, which returns the absolute value. So:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'20180522','20180520'), --returns -2
       ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,'20180522','20180520')); --returns 2
```